# How can I prove that the partial trace is well-defined?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, quantum-information, trace, quantum-error-correction

When I define the partial trace as below, how can I prove it well-defined?
I understand that I have to indicate $Tr_k(\rho)$ does not depend on how to take the ONB of $\mathbb{C}^2$
$$n\in \mathbb{Z}_{\ge 2}\\
k\in \{ 1,2,...,n\}\\
\{\mathbb{x_1},\mathbb{x_2}\}:ONB\ of \mathbb{C}^2\\
Tr_k:Mat_{2^n}(\mathbb{C})\rightarrow Mat_{2^{n-1}}(\mathbb{C)}\ 
be\ defined\ by\\
\rho\mapsto Tr_k(\rho):=\Sigma_{i=1}^2(\mathbb{I}\otimes \cdots\otimes\mathbb{I}\otimes\mathbb{x}_i^\dagger\otimes\mathbb{I}\otimes \cdots\otimes\mathbb{I})\rho (\mathbb{I}\otimes \cdots\otimes\mathbb{I}\otimes\mathbb{x}_i\otimes\mathbb{I}\otimes \cdots\otimes\mathbb{I})\ \ \Box$$

Comment: What does "ONB" mean? What is that square at the end of your last equation?

Comment: $x_i$ should not be a basis of the vector space ($\mathbb{C}^2$), but of the operators onto it.

Comment: Daniel->ONB is "orthonomal basis".

Comment: luv->What do you mean? $x_i$ is like $(1, 0)^t$ and $(0,1)^t$.

Answer (score 6):

Several ways:

1. The partial trace is the unique linear map such that $\mathrm{tr}_2(A\otimes B)=A\,\mathrm{tr}(B)$, and the trace is basis-independent.
2. The partial trace is cyclic: $$\mathrm{tr}_2(X(I\otimes B))=\mathrm{tr}_2((I\otimes B)X)\ ,$$ as can be seen by inserting a resolution of the identity. The result then follows by considering $\mathrm{tr}_2((I\otimes U))X(I\otimes U^\dagger))$, with $U$ transforming between different bases of the 2nd system.
3. Directly by inserting a resolution of the identity on the 2nd system:
   $$
   \mathrm{tr}_2(X)=\sum_i\langle i|X|i\rangle = \sum \langle i|j\rangle\langle j|X|i\rangle
   = \sum_{ij}\langle j|X|i\rangle\langle i|j\rangle = \sum_j \langle j|X|j\rangle\ .
   $$
   (Note that all bras/kets here are acting on the 2nd system only.)

Comment: When a matrix $A$ is decomposed into two ways such that $A=A_1 \otimes A_2=B_1\otimes B_2$, does a equation $A_2$tr$(A_1)=B_2$tr$(B_1)$ holds anytime?

Comment: Anytime.  The decomposition $A=A_1\otimes A_2$ is unique, up to an overall complex factor.

Comment: When $A=A_1\otimes A_2$,  $A=A_1\otimes A_2 + B_1\otimes B_2 - B_1\otimes B_2$ is also a decomposition of A, right? This is easy to show that the partial trace of the matrix is unique, but I wonder this holds at any time.

Comment: Any time. _______